# About mysql show processlist

Tags: mysql, sql

I have connected to mysql console by `mysql -uroot -p` , then use the command `show processlist ;` to list the processes , but I can't see the `result` , may be the command is too long , the column only allow around **85 characters** , the command should over the limit , how can I see the full command ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to achieve this directly from the command-line instead of logging to mysql just for that.

The command is

```
mysqladmin processlist full
```

Comment: thanks reply , I tried the command "mysqladmin processlist" , it still can not only show part of query .

Comment: @user32770 You need to specify `full` as parameter, see edit.

Answer (score 1):

You should try `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST`

> SHOW PROCESSLIST shows you which threads are running. You can also get this information from the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA PROCESSLIST` table or the `mysqladmin processlist` command. If you have the PROCESS privilege, you can see all threads. Otherwise, you can see only your own threads (that is, threads associated with the MySQL account that you are using). **If you do not use the FULL keyword, only the first 100 characters of each statement are shown in the Info field.**

If you don't use FULL, the queries are truncated in the results.